# Google deleted (from 3 accounts) a threatening email that I need as evidence of a crime-how to retrieve?

Tags: gmail, data-recovery, legal

I received a personalized threatening email that went into my spam folder ("someone" used the message board from rentboy.com to mask their identity). I sent a copy of the email to my sister (also mentioned in the threatening email) and my wife. When I went to retrieve the body of the email in question, we discovered that it had been erased from ALL 3 different accounts. How do I retrieve this email? I need this to pursue justice in a legal matter...please help!

Answer (score 1):

> ### Undelete messages
>
> You can move messages out of your Trash if you deleted them in the last 30 days.
>
> How to recover messages from your Trash:
>
> - Log in to Gmail
> - Go to your Trash or click here: **https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#trash**
> - Check the box next to any messages you want to move.
> - Click **Move to Inbox**.
> - Choose where you want to move the message to.

---

#### Note 1: Deleted emails (messages) from Trash can't be recovered!

#### Note 2: Email in Spam folder is auto-deleted after 30 days and can't be recovered!

Comment: Thank you - For the record I did not delete them-nor did the other two recipients. The email chain (from after I forwarded the "spam" / threat email) still exists- ONLY the important primary email containing the threatening message has disappeared from all three accounts.

Comment: as mentioned already spam emails are autodeleted by gmail

Comment: @user221748 https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score -1):

Most important if you have configured POP client then it grab emails from server then store it on device. only on one device then emails disappear from server (Gmail).

**Most Important**: Check your settings if you read your Gmail emails with another email client

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7015314?#zippy=%2Ccheck-your-settings-if-you-read-your-gmail-emails-with-another-email-client

If POP does not apply, you have to contact Google but before that you should try these methods. Read this page carefully.

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7015314

**Last step**: If emails are missing from your account, someone may have access without your permission.

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7015314#zippy=%2Cmost-of-my-emails-are-missing

**They will ask you to go here:**

https://support.google.com/mail/contact/missingemails?rd%3D1

I hope you are able to fix this problem. please don't forgot to provide update on what happened with Google.